# Should I prepare image of many size to fit every device when I create web app for mobile

Tags: android, iphone, web

I am writing a web app with PhoneGap.
Also, I would like to have a background image in Homepage.
However, I know there are many device with different size.
How can I fit every device and if I would like to place button in the middle of the screen, do I need to calculate the absolute position by detecting each device's width and height?
I really worry about the position of every items in the web apps.
Please help to solve.